# If a "group" has two identities then is not a group

Tags: group-theory, definition

The story goes like this: A friend and I found this old exercise:

> Let $G=\Bbb R-\{-1\}$ and $a*b:=a+b+ab$, is $(G,*)$ a group?

I say that $(G,*)$ is not a group because for any $a\in G$ follows that $0*a=0+a+0a=a+0+a0=a*0$ and also $1*a=1+a+1a=a+1+a1=a*1$, hence it has two identities. My friend says that it doesn't matter that it has two indentities since the definition we've got says that *"there exists an element such that blah blah blah"*. But I say it does matters because then what happens with the inverse, something like this happens: $0=a*a^{-1}=1 \rightarrow 0=1$ (ugly!!!). Am I right? or his evil trolling mind is right?

Or in an (absurd) way is the definition not correct?




(*There should be a tag called [settle-argument]*)

*I'm of course joking*

Comment: But $1\ast a \neq a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh! that's true...

Comment: It is not possible at all for a binary operation to have two distinct (two-sided) identity elements. If $a$, $b$ are both identity elements for $*$, then $a = a*b = b$, where the left equality is due to $b$ being an identity, and the right is due to $a$ being an identity element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1*a=2a+1\not\equiv a$ and so $1$ is **not** an identity.  Instead, what you demonstrated is that $1$ is a non-trivial center, which all elements other than $0$ will be since this operation is abelian.  It is not possible for a set to have two distinct left-right identities, since if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are identities, then $e_1*e_2=e_1$ and $e_1*e_2=e_2$ and so $e_1=e_2$.

Comment: So I lost the argument, oh... Ok, but now I'm getting confused for the way the definition of group is given in regards of the identity, it says that there exists an element $e\in G$ such that  $e*a=a*e\forall a\in G$, why doesn't it say from the beginning "there exists only one element"? why prove it afterwards?

Comment: If you can prove something in a definition, then it's a bad definition and there's no need to include it.  Also, the definition of an identity $e\in G$ is $a*e=e*a=a\ \forall a\in G$.  Your definition describes the center of a group, which I alluded to earlier.